# What software is Hans Rosling using in this presentation?

Tags: slideshow, presentations

In Hans Rosling's presentation on Human Development Trends he shows a scatter plot which explodes in to subsets of data. Does anyone know what software was used to create this presentation? I have played with the gapminder software and trendalyzer already and know that they are not capable of doing this.

Here is a link to the entire slideshow: [Gapminder Website](http://www.gapminder.org/downloads/human-development-trends-2005/)

Comment: Since your question doesn't involve programming, it is off-topic for this site. It may be a better fit for [superuser](http://superuser.com/). If you wait a couple minutes, it will likely be migrated there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got an email back from Gapminder, this presentation was handmade in flash.

Answer (score 1):

@fideli - Thanks for the clarification. I am looking for the software that generated the flash. To answer your question about his other software, he is using Gapminder. You can check it out [HERE](http://gapminder.org). If you would like to use your own data, Google has adopted the technology from trendalyzer and is available at:

code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html

Comment: Sorry for the blatant plug but it is on-topic. I just put a new Mac app online for doing exactly that type of video presentation. With an input-file prepared, it takes about 5 minutes to get an HD video including the nice "bloom" effect that you find  in the "200 Years that Changed the World" video. Of course you still need to add the voice-over and you won't see yourself either in the video either. Take a look at the demos on [popchartsapp.com](http://popchartsapp.com).

Answer (score 0):

For the backend  I have researched a bit , the programming language is "R".

There are many libraries! E.g. "ggplot2".

I am sure there are also some specifically created by the Gapminder-Foundation-Trendalyzer-Team and probably not known to the general public since Google's buy of the Trendalyzer-Software.